# how to add a DataFrame to some columns of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a DataFrame a (containing a loadprofile) to some of the columns of another DataFrame b (also containing one load profile per column). So some columns (load profiles) of b should be overlaid withe the load profile of a.

So lets say my DataFrames look like:

a:

```
  P[kW]
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   8
4   8
5   0
```

b:

```
  P1[kW]  P2[kW] ... Pn[kW]
0   2       2          2
1   3       3          3
2   3       3          3
3   4       4          4
4   2       2          2
5   2       2          2
```

Now I want to overlay some colums of b:

```
b.iloc[:, [1]] += a.iloc[:, 0]
```

I would expect this:

b:

```
  P1[kW]  P2[kW] ... Pn[kW]
0   2       2          2
1   3       3          3
2   3       3          3
3   4       12         4
4   2       10         2
5   2       2          2
```

but what I actually get:

b:

```
  P1[kW]  P2[kW] ... Pn[kW]
0   2       nan        2
1   3       nan        3
2   3       nan        3
3   4       nan        4
4   2       nan        2
5   2       nan        2
```

That's not exactly what my code and data look like, but the principle is the same as in this abstract example.

Any guesses, what could be the problem?

Many thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT:**
I actually have to overlay more than one column.
Another example:

```
load = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
data = pd.DataFrame(load)
for i in range(1, 10):
    data[i] = data[0]
data
```

[image]

```
overlay = pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0,6,6,0])
overlay
```

[image]

```
data.iloc[:, [1,2,4,5,7,8]] += overlay.iloc[:, 0]
data
```

[image]

**WHAT??!** The result is completely crazy. Columns 1 and 2 aren't changed at all. Columns 4 and 5 are changed, but in every row. Columns 7 and 8 are nans. What am I missing?

That is what I would expect the result to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not pass the column `index '1' of dataframe 'b'` as a list but as an element.

**Code**

```
b.iloc[:, 1] += a.iloc[:, 0]
b
```

**Output**

```
    P1[kW]  P2[kW]  Pn[kW]
0   2       2       2
1   3       3       3
2   3       3       3
3   4       12      4
4   2       10      2
5   2       2       2
```

#### Edit

Seems like this what we are looking for i.e `to sum certain columns of data df with overlay df`

**Two Options**

**Option 1**

```
cols=[1,2,4,5,7,8]
data[cols] = data[cols] + overlay.values
data
```

**Option 2, if we want to use iloc**

```
cols=[1,2,4,5,7,8]
data[cols] = data.iloc[:,cols] + overlay.iloc[:].values
data
```

**Output**

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   6   6   0   6   6   0   6   6   0
5   0   6   6   0   6   6   0   6   6   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks :) It works if I only overlay 1 column. But when I want to choose more columns to overlay, I have to pass them as a list, right? And that is where things start to get __real__ crazy: some columns are overlaid correctly, some are nans, some are overlaid, but with different values?!? I feel like going crazy

Comment: nw, I have updated the solution as per requirement.

Comment: __THANK YOU!! :)__  You have literally saved my day! I was short about smacking my head against the wall :D  I would give you multiple upvotes, if that was possible

Comment: np, I was able to save you some time that's the biggest reward for me. All the best!